# Mysql multiple count column wise each having seperate conditions

Tags: mysql, count

can anyone help me to solve the mysql query:-

```
select 
  (select 
     count(bug_id) 
   from 
     bugs 
   where 
     bugs.priority="P3") as P3count,
  (select count(bug_id) from bugs where bugs.priority="P2") as P2count 
from 
  bugs 
where 
  bugs.product_id=237 and 
  bugs.bug_status='RESOLVED' and 
  bugs.resolution='FIXED' and 
  bugs.creation_ts >= '2013-06-14 09:00:00' and 
  bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59' 
group by 
  priority;
```

I **need to get** the result:-

```
+---------+----------+ 
| P3count |  P2count |                                                                                                                                          
+---------+----------+                                                                                                                                          
|       7 |     8    |                                                                                                                                      
+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `COUNT`, you use `SUM` to count the rows by adding `1` for each matching row. The expression `IF(condition,1,0)` evaluates to `1` if the condition is true, and `0` otherwise.

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(priority="P3",1,0)) P3count,
    SUM(IF(priority="P2",1,0)) P2count,
    ...
FROM bugs
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the sum(if) condition